# Issue with fetching data in a One to Many relationship in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, dao, many-to-one

I tried to make the question smaller, but I could not make it smaller :(

I have 2 entities and this is how they are related:

```
Collection (1) ----> (n) Item
Item (0 or 1) -----> (n) Item
```

i.e. each `Item` is related to a `Collection`. Further each `Item` can have 0 or more children `Item`. In case there is a child `Item`, the child `Item` will have a non-null `parent_item_id`;

**Tables:**

Collections

```
collection_id raw
```

Items

```
item_id raw
collection_id raw
parent_item_id raw
```

**Mappings :**

```
class Collections
{
   @Id @Column("collection_id")
   String id;

   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="collection")
   List<Items> items;
}

class Items
{
  @Id @Column("item_id")
  String id;

  @ManyToOne(optional=false)
  @JoinColumn(name="collection_id")
  Collections collection;

  @ManyToOne(optional=true)
  @JoinColumn(name="parent_item_id")
  Items parentItem;
}
```

Suppose I have created an object like this:

```
//Constructor parameters are the Ids.
Collections collection1 = new Collections("1234");
Items i1 = new Items("111");
Items i2 = new Items("222");
item1.parentItem = item2;
item1.collection = collection1;
item2.collection = collection1;
List<Items> listItems = new ArrayList<Items>(1);
listItems.add(item2);
collection1.items = listItems;
```

We have a Data Access Layer (DA) which is a wrapper around JPA with Hibernate.
Next, I perform two operations:

```
Collections collection1 = DA.merge(collection1);
Collections collection2 = DA.find(collection1.id);
```

I would expect `collection2.items.size()` to return 2. But it returns 1. (PS : there are actually 2 items related to the collection1).

Can it be explained? Is it expected or is it a bug in DA? Does JPA cache the Collection?

Later, if in a different transaction, I try to fetch `Collections collectionNew = DA.find("1234").items.size()` it returns 2 (expected);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the items.size() in collection1 before and after the merge?  JPA entities are regular objects, so if the size isn't 2, it wont be after a find unless you refresh the entity back from the database.

Comment: Yes it is 1. Okay, I see. and How do I force it to fetch from database?

Comment: Maintain both sides of bidirectional relationships is the better approach, or you can use em.refresh after a comit or flush to get changes.